# Is Ajax secured? Which method is more secured for cascading dropdown in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a project which is in Web form! Here Cascading dropdown is implemented via default click event or action listener. Now I want to switch to MVC. My database is Oracle here! So which method will be efficient and secured for implementing cascading dropdown? Will ajax request be a better idea or there are something else to implement the cascading dropdown?

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for implementing cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke Which is more secure? Using .change or using ajax?

Comment: What do you mean using `.change()` - that is a client side event and has nothing ti do with ajax or calling a server method. And what do you mean by 'secure'? (an ajax call is no more or less secure than a normal post - you implement security in the server, not the client)